# How to merge multiple JSON files reading from S3, convert to single .csv and store in S3?

Tags: json, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Input :
There are 5 part **JSON** files named as test_par1.json, test_part2.json, test_part3.json, test_part4.json, test_part5.json in s3://test/json_files/data/.

Expected Output :
Single **csv** file

Explanation : All of the json files are having same number of columns with same structure. They are basically part files of same source.
I want to merge/re partition all of them and convert them into a csv file and store it in S3.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import boto3
import numpy

# Boto3 clients
resource  = boto3.resource('s3')
client = boto3.client('s3')
session = boto3.session.Session()

bucket = 'test'
path = 'json_files/data/'
delimiter = '/'
suffix = '.json'
json_files = client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=path, Delimiter=delimiter)
#print(inter_files)
for obj in inter_files['Contents']:
    #print(obj)
    obj = client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=obj['Key'])
    #print(obj)
    df = pd.read_json(obj["Body"], lines=True)
    print(df)
```

Comment: Which part of the task do you actually experience difficulty with?

Comment: I'm finding difficulties with merging/re partitioning multiple json files and creating a single csv file.

Comment: Do you know how to retrieve files from S3 and how to parse JSON?

Comment: Actually I implemented the code using local file system ! But S3 it's becoming difficult ! I can retrieve files from s3.

Comment: If you can do this locally then you'll only need to download the files and upload the result. This should not be difficult.

Comment: I want to avoid that ! I don't want to implement this locally. I want this whole operation to be done in S3 level. I don't want any part of this to be done locally.

Comment: You could take a look at [Amazon S3 Batch Operations](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/features/batch-operations/). Otherwise, the "usual" solution would be to download, process, and then upload.